# Using KnpMenuBundle in Symfony2 for menu of Entities?

Tags: symfony

I have a `User` entity and all users have many `Category` entities.  I have a controller which accepts a `Category` slug as a parameter.

I would like to render a menu that lists all of the `Category`'s of a `User` as links to that controller.  I would also like to mark one as "current" if they are on that page already.

The KnpMenuBundle looks nice for this https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

But all of its examples use a static menu that is built up, rather than building the menu from dynamic items.  **I thought about getting the items in the `Builder`, but I already have them in the controller that ultimately renders the twig template, so I would rather somehow pass these `Category`'s to the `Builder` and let it handle rendering a menu.**

What is the best way to do this?

My other idea is to just do the menu myself in twig, but I would need extra logic to determine which page is "current"

Comment: Knp is quite static, it can be extended, but wont be so flexible anyway. In my opinion Knp is nothing more than just some setters / getters. My problem is quite common: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316709/symfony-2-autogenerated-navigation-menus and yet, no implementation exists. Let me know if you find anything useful.

Comment: Matt have you found solution for this?

Comment: Nope, just not using this bundle

Answer (score 0):

I know that this might not be useful to you anymore but for others viewing the question maby this is helpful.
Since recently it is possible to send your own variables from twig to the builder.

It's done like this as noted in the [Documentation](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#rendering-menus):

```
{% set menuItem = knp_menu_get('AcmeDemoBundle:Builder:mainMenu', [], {
        'some_option': 'my_value'
    }) 
%}

{{ knp_menu_render(menuItem) }}
```

Comment: I assume that 'some-option' can be replaced by "id", "class" or anything that will be set for the main <ul> element. But it is not working for me. Am I missing something? Should I wrap class/id in a "attributes" array? Thanks.

Comment: You can indeed change `some_option` with "id" or "class". Then inside the menu builder you get them from the `$options` parameter: ` public function mainMenu(FactoryInterface $factory, array $options)`, so `$options['id']` or `$options['class']`. From there you can do what you want with them.